# Test automation with Selenium and TeamCity

Tags: selenium, teamcity, functional-testing

I'm trying to design a cross-browser web app build automation using TeamCity that would do something like this:

1. Take the sources from the VCS
2. Build the web app
3. Deploy the app to a test server
4. Run tests on several VMs/Build agent with appropriate browser (versions) installed
5. Deploy to a staging server (for human testing) if everything went fine

I'm a bit confused about the step 4. It's far from trivial, and I already figured out that there are going to be separate build configurations, so each can run on a separate build agent, but that's where I lose it.

Is it possible to build such a config, or do I have to schedule Test Build configurations that run on different Build Agents separately?

Another question is - how do I get a Build configuration to copy something that's been built with another configuration to the Agent running the build?

I mean - so far I only used build agents to actually build something and optionally run unit tests against something that's just been built, but this introduces another dimension, and I'm not sure if it's possible at all.

Thanks
v.

Answer (score 0):

I have met this problem with javaScript testing. For which I did not need to copy to a remote server first.

My solution was to use Qunit and NQUnit. However NQUnit has a hard-coded tie to Watin, which only supports IE.

So I got the source of NQUnit and fairly trivially changed it to use Selenium Web Drivers. I can now run a c# unit test which triggers NQunit, which in turn triggers every browser and returns results for each browser test.

This would mean just one instance of a Build Agent.